# What exception does MS Test throw when the test run is abruptly stopped(perhaps in the task manager or because of a crash)

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, mstest

I am trying to run a set of tests in MS Test and log the results. If the test is abruptly stopped during the run, I would like the state to be saved. How can I accomplish this?
Does MS Test throw any exception before ending the test?

Answer (score 0):

If what MSTest is testing crashes in any way, MSTest will do it's best to record it.  A hard unmanaged crash, say, that translates into an AccessViolationException is bad and anything could happen including silent exit.  If MSTest is interrupted with Ctrl-C, it will be caught and noted, I think after the current test is finished.  If MSTest is stopped using Task Manager with "End Process" this translates into Win32 `TerminateProcess` which unconditionally causes the process to exit with no recourse for any sort of handling.  Perhaps you could print something out at the end and if it is not in the log then you can assume it was interrupted.